# Regex Match Variable Length String By Prefix and Suffix

Tags: .net, regex

I have checked several other questions on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758922/regexp-how-to-select-a-string-depending-on-a-prefix-and-a-suffix-but-not-them), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176298/get-part-of-the-string-if-with-conditional-prefix-and-suffix), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968800/regex-to-match-a-whole-string-only-if-it-lacks-a-given-substring-suffix), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395928/difficulty-with-simple-regex-match-prefix-suffix), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632/can-you-make-just-part-of-a-regex-case-insensitive), but I can't seem to figure out my issue from any of these. It is quite likely that I'm missing something simple, but I don't know what.

I have a string like the following:
`This is some random text{colA}that needs{COLBB} to be matched.`

I need to match on the `A` and the `BB` but nothing else. The rules are as follows

- The prefix will only be {col (case insensitive)
- The suffix will only be }
- The characters to match will only be letters
- The match must be case insensitive
- The match will only be 1 or 2 characters
- A word break can't be assumed before or after the prefix/suffix

I managed to get this: `(?i:[a-z]{1,2}(?<={col[a-z]{1,2})(?=}))` which matches `{colaa}` but not `{cola}` (In the case of `{cola}` it returns `la` when it needs to return `a`). I can't figure out how to tune this to work with the two different match cases.

I'm working in .Net and would really appreciate any help I could get on this matter. I feel so close, yet so far away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to move the lookbehind assertion to the beginning of the pattern, so we can specify the *exact* prefix, rather than having to assert on the prefix *plus* the matched part. So:

```
(?i:(?<=\{col)[a-z]{1,2}(?=\}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?i:(?<={col)[A-Za-z]{1,2}(?=}))
```

- The whole expression is case insensitive: `(?i: … )`
- We assert that the match must be preceded by "{col" with a lookbehind: `(?<={col)`
- We match any one to two letters of any case: `[A-Za-z]{1,2}`
- We assert that the match must be followed by "}" with a lookahead: `(?=})`

Comment: Since we are matching case insensitive the [A-Za-z] can be [a-z].